# JDBC update of different fields

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sql-update, dao

I'm developing Web Service that has access to database via JDBC. I'm using DAO pattern. I've implemented all necessary methods: findAll, add, update, delete. But I got confused with update method. It has Object as input parameter. But how does he know which field needs to be updated. For example, I need to update field 'name' I use query `'update table set name='smth where id=2'` but if I need to update 'surname'?? what is the best practice to tell update method what actually to update?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change your method signature to include a Map of column names and values.

```
public interface FooDao<K, V> {
    // other methods here, of course.
    public void update(V target, Map<String, Object> parameters); 
}
```

Have a look at the Spring JDBC template for a nice example of how to design and implement such a thing.

Comment: do you mean this? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html   Thank you, I will read

Comment: Spring is at version 3; I think it might be worth it to get the latest.  And I meant looking at the javadocs for the SimpleJdbcTemplate to see how they thought about it.